# SassError: compound selectors may no longer be extended

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

I face this error in my react app when I run npm start..I'm using node : v14.17.6 & npm: 6.14.9

Failed to compile.

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
SassError: compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend .dropdown-item, .active` instead.
See https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#disallowed-selectors  for details.

╷
16 │     @extend .dropdown-item.active;
│             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\assets\scss\bootstrap_typeaheadjs.scss 16:13  root stylesheet

This is _typeaheadjs.scss content

```
span.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;

  .tt-menu {
    @extend .dropdown-menu;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tt-suggestion {
    @extend .dropdown-item;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    @extend .dropdown-item.active;
  }

  .input-group & {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 1%;

    .tt-menu, .tt-hint, .tt-input {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the bootstrap_typeaheadjs.scss file on the line 16, to see why we think you have wrong

Comment: I added _typeaheadjs.scss file in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#disallowed-selectors):

The definition of @extend says that elements matching the extender would be styled as though they matched .message.info. That’s just the same as matching both .message and .info, so there wouldn’t be any benefit in writing that instead of @extend .message, .info.

```
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  @extend .dropdown-item, active;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I corrected But faced with new error :
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
Error: Can't resolve './fonts/themify.eot' in 'H:\react-admin\back-end\src'

Comment: Themify.eot is in : src/assests/fonts/Themify.eot

Comment: @Gandom you should create a separate question